# Get the Percentage by given two amount in range bar using php

Tags: php, calculator

I wont to get percentage between 0% to 100% by using destination amount($3500) and my funded amount. I view many example and use it but not work proper. i wont to display my funded amount($2000).

[image]

Comment: what is the result you are looking for?

Comment: for ex. if total fund amount is $1000 and funded amount is $5oo than it should be display 50% .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by simple maths calculation,
Your designation amount is 100%, you need is percent age of amount funded.

```
<code>
    $designation_amt = 1000;
    $funded_amt = 500;
    $des_one_percent = $designation_amt / 100;
    $result_percent = $funded_amt / $des_one_percent;
    echo $result_percent; // the percentage you required.
</code>
```

This code can also be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the percentage by following method:

eg:

```
your value : 2000;

max value: 3500

max percentage : 100
```

you can just multiple your value to max percentage and divide the result by max value. ie : (2000 * 100) / 3500  = 57.14. you can round the value and thus show this value on the bar

Comment: moreover you can just keep changing the funding value to whateva eg: 3000. then you get the percentage accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

```
100 / (fund_amount/funded_amount) = Your_percentage
100 / (1000 / 500) = 50%
100 / (3500 / 2000) = 57.142%
```